# Dart: testing private methods by accessing mock's property

Tags: unit-testing, dart, testing, mockito, private-methods

I'm trying to get a mocked object property. During the initialization, 'child' class is getting a reference to a parent's private function. I'd like to catch this reference during testing to check parent's private method.

This is a simplified example of much more complex code:

```
class Monkey{

final name;
final Perk _perk;


Monkey('Maya', this._perk){
this._perk.jump = this._jump;
  }

void _jump(int a){ // here's the problem, not able to test private method
print('jump ${a}');
  }

}
```

All I want to do is to be able to test private method _jump during testing in mockito. I don't want to change the code.
During test I created

```
class MockPerk extends Mock implements Perk{}
Monkey(mockedPerk);
```

What I want to achieve is:

1. Create Monkey instance with mockedPerk
2. Capture property `_perk.jump` in `MockedPerk` class
3. Get reference to private `_jump` method of `Moneky's` class to be able to test it.

Limitation

1. Making method public is not an option.
2. Making method public with `@visibleForTesting` is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture values passed to setters with `verify(mock.setter = captureAny)`.  For example:

```dart
  var mockedPerk = MockPerk();
  var monkey = Monkey('Maya', mockedPerk);
  var jump = verify(mockedPerk.jump = captureAny).captured.single as void
      Function(int);
  jump(5); // Prints: jump 5
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks a lot for your rapid support. I played with arguments capturing before but I was not aware to use it this way.

Comment: How to capture setter values is not documented very well.  I had to look at `package:mockito`'s unit tests to see examples for how to do it.  Also, if this answered your question, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: I would also like to ask how can I detect if any function have been called inside of non mocked class? Is it possible?

Comment: In general, you can't.  You would need to have the class use callbacks instead of invoking the function directly ("dependency inversion/injection").